# Using OpenCV with PyInstaller: ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

I am getting an error when trying to create a binary executable of a Python program with PyInstaller. However, there seems to be some issue with the config.py file. If I try to import cv2, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "exec_test.py", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/me/path/to/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
File "site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 58, in bootstrap
File "site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 56, in load_first_config
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. 
Check OpenCV installation.
[10914] Failed to execute script exec_test
```

I am using the following code:

```
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello, world!")
```

which is totally fine when I run it with Python.

To compile the executable, I am running:

```
pyinstaller --onefile local-processing/exec_test.py
```

When the PyInstaller runs, it has the following output:

```
50 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
50 INFO: Python: 3.7.2
55 INFO: Platform: Darwin-17.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
56 INFO: wrote /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/exec_test.spec
59 INFO: UPX is not available.
60 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/me/path/to/neural-network/local-processing',
 '/Users/me/path/to/neural-network']
60 INFO: checking Analysis
66 INFO: Building because /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/local-processing/exec_test.py changed
66 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
68 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
70 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2885 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2891 INFO: Caching module hooks...
2894 INFO: Analyzing /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/local-processing/exec_test.py
3366 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
3366 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py'
4023 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
4409 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
4410 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/Users/me/path/to/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
6439 INFO: Loading module hooks...
6439 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
6921 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
6923 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.py"...
6923 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
6977 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
7237 WARNING: Hidden import "distutils.command.build_ext" not found!
7467 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cv2.py"...
7468 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
7474 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
7536 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
7590 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
7590 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
7618 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7651 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7655 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
7656 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
7666 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7802 INFO: Looking for eggs
7802 INFO: Using Python library /Users/me/path/to/.env/bin/../.Python
7809 INFO: Warnings written to /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/build/exec_test/warn-exec_test.txt
7856 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/build/exec_test/xref-exec_test.html
7875 INFO: checking PYZ
7878 INFO: Building because toc changed
7878 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/build/exec_test/PYZ-00.pyz
8535 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/build/exec_test/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
8549 INFO: checking PKG
8550 INFO: Building because toc changed
8550 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
15351 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
15355 INFO: Bootloader /Users/me/path/to/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Darwin-64bit/run
15355 INFO: checking EXE
15356 INFO: Building because toc changed
15356 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
15357 INFO: Appending archive to EXE /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/dist/exec_test
15368 INFO: Fixing EXE for code signing /Users/me/path/to/neural-network/dist/exec_test
15372 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

I am using Python 3.7.2, OpenCV version 4.0.1 and PyInstaller version 3.4 with a virtualenv version 16.3.0 on a macOS High Sierra. Please let me know if any other information would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure your OpenCV and Pyinstaller versions are up to date with:

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```

You can always try a fresh install as well.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately, this did not work. I got the same error. Would you happen to have any other suggestions.Thanks!

Comment: It seems the problem may be a corrupted installation of OpenCV. I would remove all instances of OpenCV in site-packages and do a complete reinstall.

Comment: I did that. Previously, I had installed OpenCV with Homebrew, but in order to follow your suggestion, I uninstalled it and installed it with pip. The new installation still works if I run it as a python program, but not when I try to run a pyinstaller executable.

Comment: I made sure there was nothing about opencv in the following folders `.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`, `/usr/local/opt/`, and `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`.

Comment: Interesting. Its probably on Pyinstaller's end then. You could try uninstall/reinstall Pyinstaller the same way as OpenCV. If that doesn't work then it could be due to incompatible OpenCV hook imports. I've fixed this hook issue by downgrading the package version.

Comment: I just deleted the virtual environment and created a new one. That seemed to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Get the path of the cv2 in python  and add while compiling :

```
import cv2 
print(cv2.file) # /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.so
    
/home:~$ pyinstaller --onefile --paths="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6" main.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem not long ago.
To solve that issue on Windows, it's pretty similar. The difference is that you have to make sure that you found the proper folder where pyinstaller is loading info from, because it's tricky once you have other instances other than the cv2 container. In my machine, for example, I could only solve it when I passed the path as --path=AppData\Local\pyinstaller\bincache00_py39_64bit\cv2 Add that flag at the end of your pyinstaller command and everything should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you sir! I had the same issue on Windows 10, tried all other method, reinstall, used print(cv2.__file__) route, but none of it worked. Until I've found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to include

```
"--collect-all opencv-python"
```

to your original code, which then becomes:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --collect-all opencv-python local-processing/exec_test.py
```

Comment: When I tried this I got the warning:  `WARNING: collect_data_files - skipping data collection for module 'opencv-python' as it is not a package.`

Comment: Hello Joel, did you use pip install opencv-python to install opencv?