# how use pyinstaller with opencv in raspbian?

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller, raspbian

i wrote this python script "mycv.py" in raspbian:

```
import cv2 as cv
```

and it debug and run currectly. then i use pyinstaller to make executable file.
but when run file in terminal. it has error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "cv2/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
  File "cv2/__init__.py", line 58, in bootstrap
  File "cv2/__init__.py", line 56, in load_first_config
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.
[28400] Failed to execute script mycv
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175419/using-opencv-with-pyinstaller</a>
He have the same error and find a good solution. may it hel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of debugging, I found the following solution:

1. Get the path of OpenCV

   import cv2
   print(cv2.**file**) # /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.so
2. Add this path while compiling through pyinstaller

   pyinstaller main.py -n myApp --paths="/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6"

I hope this helps others also