# failed to execute script py to exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I read 10+ related topics but neither one of them had a solution for me.

I have the following modules included:

```
import sys
import os
import cv2
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
```

And tried several methods:

- pyinstaller.exe -F --onefile --windowed --hidden-import "cv2" --icon=arc.ico tkinter_popup.py (it opens  a console but then my system deletes it automatically for being malicious
- pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=arc.ico tkinter_popup.py (Fatal error - can't access script)
- pyinstaller.exe --icon=arc.ico tkinter_popup.py (Fatal error - can't access script)

It doesn't matter if it will work as single folder or single file. I prefer a single file output but if isn't possible a single folder will work as well.

I tried with 3.8.5 and 3.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show a [example] please? What's there in the script?

Comment: > my system deletes it automatically for being malicious -> You can try to turn off Windows Defender, or alternatively make sure that your computer isn't infected. This isn't something that other people can easily reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have chosen an icon that was used both as icon and as logo. After I compiled it without that icon, everything works and both laptops. If I wanted to specify the full path, than it worked only on my laptop, that has that specific user(path). If I wanted to specify only the icon path ex 'ico.icon', than it was generating a fatal error. After deleting the icon and all the references to it, everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What I personally do with these kind of errors, is using the python `logging` module to produce a log file whenever a fatal error occurs, such that I know what happens. Then it is much easier to debug it afterwards

What you should do is wrap your entire script in a try/except block, where the exception is written to the log file

Something along the following lines (log file is only created when an error occurs)

```py
import logging
lh = logging.FileHandler(filename='mf_timer.log', mode='w', delay=True)
logging.basicConfig(handlers=[lh],
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

try:
    <enter your main script here (including imports)>
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
    raise e
```

Add this to your code, then recreate the executable, and run it. You should now get a log file where the error is shown

Comment: on my personal laptop everything works fine with -f --onefile --windowed but on my work laptop it says no cv2 module was found. How it is possible? Because the script was developed on my work laptop. And if I try to --hidden-import "cv2" , when I run the exe it is instantly deleted and I can't disable any defenders obviously

Comment: @Psko You can try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55175419/using-opencv-with-pyinstaller maybe updating your packages will help..? Sounds to be related to your python installation not being identical between your personal and work laptop

Comment: I have upgraded the packages. I have compiled it on my personal laptop and send it on my work laptop and on the work laptop I get the Fatal error unable to open script, when I am trying to run the executable. The whole idea of one single file compilation isn't to have all the necessary files in one place so that you can send the file where do you want to who ever do you want?

Comment: And if you run the script directly from python on your work computer, you have no issue?

Comment: @Psko according to this page, https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/, you might want to use `pip install opencv-python-headless` instead of the standard installation of `opencv` - could perhaps solve it

Comment: ahahaha. You know Tkinter has a blue feather as an icon. I have chosen another icon that was both as icon and as logo. After I compiled it  without that icon, everything works and both laptops. How it is possible? If I wanted to specify the full path, than it worked only on my laptop, that has that specific user(path). If I wanted to specify only the icon path ex 'ico.icon', than it was generating a fatal error. After deleting the icon and all the references to it, everything works like a charm. I still wonder....why it says it's the cv2 module that is missing if it was an icon problem...